# Elasticsearch: sort by field with null values last

Tags: elasticsearch

I want sort by `name`, but keep entries with null or missing `price` data at the end of the results.

I have tried:

```
sort: {
    sorting.name: {
        order: "asc"
    },
    prices.minprice.price: {
        missing: "_last"
    }
}
```

but this only sorts by name.

Comment: Try reversing the sequence of the sort params. With the order you have specified it is sorting by name and then by price only if name is same.     Try as:    {
    "sort" : [
        { "prices.minprice.price" : {"missing":"_last"}},
        { "sorting.name" : {"order":"asc"} ]
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this we can use a custom function score ([which is faster than custom script based sorting according to elasticsearch documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting)). When price is missing, the numeric value will return 0.

We then sort on score first to split into a section with missing price data, and a section without missing price data, and then sort each of these two sections based on name.

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "boost_mode": "replace",
            "query": {"match_all": {}},
            "script_score": {
                "script": "doc['price'].value == 0 ? 0 : 1"
            }   
        }
    },
    "sort": [
       "_score",
       "name"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you but, My first criterion of sort have to be by name. No prices data should be at the end. This e.g. sorting by price.

Comment: See my updated answer - this question was a lot more complicated than I originally thought, I've tested the above though and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for scritp score, that works. But I cant access field which has child. When I try  doc['prices.2015-07-16.price'].value > 0 ? 1 : 0 allways return 0. Data Like ; 
"prices": {
    "2015-07-16": {
        "staticPrice": 415,
        "price": 290.5,
        "conceptId": 4,
        "currencyId": 1
    }

Comment: Instead of doc['field'].value try _source.field.subfield instead. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html

Comment: Is this answer still valid with ElasticSearch 6.x ??  Or now we have better solution?

Answer (score 10):

Actually you could use the `missing` order.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#_missing_values

Comment: Note that if you sort by a value in a nested object you might need to also set the [nested path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#nested-sorting) for `missing` to work on the nested nulls.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me,

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting

```
"sort":[
      {
         "_script":{
            "type":"number",
            "script":{
               "lang":"painless",
               "source":"return params._source.store[0].sku_available_unit == 0 ? 0 : 1;"
            },
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
    ]
```